# How to change date in text box to desired format when something changed in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, underscore.js, datetimepicker

I have a form which has bunch of input text boxes with date picker (datepicker.js). When user changes value in locale dropdown, I am changing the date format and reinitializing the date picker with that local specific format. If user has already entered/selected date in the textbox and changes locale then I want that date to be automatically get converted into that desired format.

For example if user has selected the date when locale drop down shows en_US and date will be 04/30/2016, if he changes the locale drop down to en_UK then I want the date to be shown as 30/04/2016 in the text box. I tried few libraries, but none of them seems to be simple. Can we do it in JQuery or UnderscorJS or in simple javascript?

```
dateFormat = (currentLocale == that.defaultLocale) ? 'm/d/Y' : 'd/m/Y';

            var options = {
                lazyInit : false, // Lazy init to prevent a lot of instances right away
                timepicker : false,
                format : dateFormat,
                minDate: 0,
                closeOnDateSelect: true
            };

                $('input.datetime').datetimepicker(options);
                if(currentLocale == that.defaultLocale)
                    $('input.datetime').attr("placeholder", "mm/dd/yyyy");
                else
                    $('input.datetime').attr("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? :

```
    function getFormattedDate(date) {
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
        month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
        var day = date.getDate().toString();
        day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
        return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
     }
```

Comment: I cannot use any new library apart from what is mentioned above (JQuery or UnderscorJS or in simple javascript), Just for this purpose we dont want to add a new library

Comment: Have you tried formatting it with your own function using native javascript: something like: (date = new Date("02/20/2012"); date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear();   *See updated code for quick example

Comment: Yes...something like that, I thought there may be something inbuilt in jquery